# Overriding Django's default id in it's User Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-modeladmin

We have a working Django project in a multi-master database environment. That means the we have multiple instances of the project's database running in separate machines and that all individual changes are propagated to the other databases. Is working very well in this setup and without any issues.

Up to now, we were not using Django's Auth tooling, meaning that there was not user login or password. That has to change. For this to work in our replication environment, thou, we need to change User's default id to something akin of a UUID to avoid collisions when the replications occurs.

So, the challenge at hand is this: how to change the id field of the User model in the Auth App? We don't have any other specific requirement except this. We don't need any extra field and anything. Just to change the id.

In the case that writing our own custom User model is inescapable maybe someone could point us at some good blog post about it or share any other resource.

Ideally we would like to preserve everything else. including access to admin's interface, groups and permissions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `User` class by extending base class as defined [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project)

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField()
```

and in `settings.py` set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` as defined [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'
```